# How to loop through returned json data in jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is the json that i am returning from the server:

{row_1:9.07,row_2:10.94,row_3:5.02,row_4:98.9007,row_5:6.97,row_5:.,row_7:11.05}

This list will be dynamic. How can I retrieve the data in the jquery ajax routine: This is what I have tried:

```
for(var i=1; i<= $("#total").val(); i++){

  $('#result_' + i).html(data.row_ + i); // How can I get the returned data?

  }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid [**JSON**](http://json.org/example).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value of **#total** is equal to the number of properties in the object, you could do the following:

```
var response = {
    row_1: 9.07,
    row_2: 10.94,
    row_3: 5.02,
    row_4: 98.9007,
    row_5: 6.97,
    row_5: 0.0,
    row_7: 11.05
};

for (var i = 1; i <= $("#total").val(); i++) {
    $('#result_' + i).html(response['row_' + i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to parse it manually, consider using the built-in JSON parser that comes with JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rawJSON = '{"pets":[{"name":"Rose"},{"name":"Martha"},{"name":"The Doctor"}]}';
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(rawJSON);
    for(var i = 0; i<obj.pets.length; i++) {
      $("#result_" + i).html(obj.pets[i].name);
    } // end for loop
</script>
```